# How to add points of each group in ggplot to the boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have data that I need to make clustered boxplot for, here is a sample:

```
data = structure(list(Cluster = c("1 Cluster", "3 Clusters", "5 Clusters", 
"4 Clusters", "2 Clusters", "1 Cluster", "1 Cluster", "2 Clusters", 
"1 Cluster", "1 Cluster"), Seed = c(11L, 15L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 
7L, 8L, 19L, 6L, 18L), Algorithm = structure(c(7L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 7L), levels = c("RF", "BRNN", "SVR", "KNN", 
"GP", "XGB", "NNET"), class = "factor"), MAPE = c(112.14, 103.27, 
109.68, 123.03, 115.13, 113.14, 117.47, 145.57, 140.04, 117.33
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I produced the following plot [image: Boxplot]. I would like to show each Algorithm's MAPE during Seed = 11. I want that value to take a black color with a different shape for each Algorithm. I tried adding it using the following command:

```
Seed11 = data%>% filter(Seed=="11")
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Cluster, y = MAPE, color = Algorithm))+geom_boxplot(size = 1.25)+
  geom_point(data = Seed11, aes(x = Cluster, y = MAPE,color = Algorithm, shape = Algorithm, size = 2))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text( angle = 0 ,vjust = 0.5, hjust=0.5, colour = "black", size = 20, face = "bold"), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size =20, face = "bold"), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(1), angle = 90),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = rel(2), angle = 40), 
        plot.title =element_text(size=14,face ="bold"))+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Algorithm"))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 10))+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("MAPE (%)")+
  theme(text=element_text(size=10,  family="serif")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1))+
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=20),
        legend.title=element_text(size=20))+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=30),
        axis.title=element_text(size=30,face="bold"))+
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(2, 'cm'), 
        legend.key.height = unit(1.5, 'cm'), 
        legend.key.width = unit(1.5, 'cm'), 
        legend.title = element_text(size=20, face = "bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(size=20, face = "bold"))
```

However, this code adds only one cluster value without separating by Algorithm. Here is the graph for [image: that]

Comment: Try with `geom_point(..., position = position_dodge(width = .75))`.